# Can't install Expo Cli using npm install -g expo-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

I tried installing explo cli on windows using `npm install -g expo-cli` and I am only getting dozens of warnings along with dozens of errors as below:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\divya>npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN rollback Rolling back is-glob@3.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\glob-parent\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.15.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.15.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.4","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @expo/configure-splash-screen@0.1.19 requires a peer of expo-splash-screen@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3 requires a peer of react-refresh@^0.8.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\divya\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinApi.dll'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\divya\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinApi.dll',
npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-25T09_25_11_308Z-debug.log

C:\Users\divya>expo
'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```